# sending automatic mail by using outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

hi i want to send email ever day at the same hour like 1630 is it possible with macros. i found some macros but they are working manually. here is a simple code:

```
Sub sendMail()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    objMail.Subject = "Hi!"
    objMail.Body = "A test mail"
    objMail.To = "...@google.com"
    objMail.Send
End Sub
```

i couldn't attached time variable can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the DeferredDeliveryTime property:

```
objMail.DeferredDeliveryTime
```

more infos [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.deferreddeliverytime.aspx)

Comment: thanks for answer but i dont get that i have to run this macro everyday or one run will be enough ?